# MVC 4.0 javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Got a mobile application and want to run a javascript. Placed the script ("startstop") in a bundle:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/startstop").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/startstop*"));
    ...
```

Included the bundle in the view:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/startstop")    
}
```

Simplified the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Hello');
});
```

When I ran the page/application, Action(s) from the *startstop-script* were not triggered/executed (`IExporer/Chrome`). However,When I copied the source of the page generated (including Scripts & Content) and opened the saved (copied) page in `IExporer/ Chrome` this startstop-script runs fine.

Anybody any idea what might be wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The full script name is startstop.js

Comment: Are you using this in a partial view?

Comment: Are you also referencing jquery at some point? Now you have given the filename, I can replicate this fine and it works, the bundle is fine. So the two remaining options I can see are, you are not calling the RegisterBundles method in global.asax, or you are not referencing the jquery script.

Comment: It is a normal view (not partial). Application_Start contains BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles); The generated pages refers the jquery, jquery-mobile and startstop scripts. The $(document).ready is normally trigger automatically.

Comment: Make sure you have referred Jquery and it comes top of this bundle.

Answer (score 1):

If the script filename ends in .min.js, it get ignored. If this is the case, try adding this to the top of your RegisterBundles function.

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
```

Edit: clarified.

Comment: The full script name is startstop.js

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but the problem is caused by @section.Scripts:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/startstop")    
}
```

Without this section the *startstop-script* works fine:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/startstop")
```

does the job.
The first case renders slightly different from the second case:

```
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/startstop.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Whereas the working variant looks like:

```
     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
     <script src="/Scripts/startstop.js"></script>
     </div>
  </div>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Still puzzles me, but it works...!